# How to show a bootstrap modal window after validation?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to create the following functionality: 
If user clicks on a menu item and all changes were saved or there were no changes, another page is loaded. If changes were not saved then bootstrap modal window should be shown.

I have a menu like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a runat="server" id="toSettings" onserverclick="toSettings_ServerClick">Settings</a</li>
     ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

and use the following structure for modal window:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h2>Changes not saved</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
           some text
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

C# code I've tried:

```
 if (saved)
 {
     Response.Redirect("anotherPage.aspx");
 }
 else
 {
     string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('#modal').modal('show'); </script>";
     ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", script);
 }
```

but modal window doesn't appear.

I suppose that something wrong with executing script in C# code.

I would be glad if someone help to correct my mistake or suggest another way to realize this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you tracking changes?

Comment: You register the script, but where/how are you calling it?

Comment: How are you tracking changes? -- 
I'm using a bool variable. First it is equal to true. If some changes were made (e.g. report table were created) I set it to false.

Comment: You register the script, but where/how are you calling it? -- I'm trying to call it from c# code but not sure that it is correct

Comment: @Ksenia : please try the code I have posted in the answer and ask if there is any difficulty with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure you have all the `jQuery-UI` and `bootstrap` css and js files with you and properly referenced in the head section.

Next write a script in the `Master-Page` if you have one or in the same page at the end of the page, like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

Then I could call the modal popup from code-behind with the following:

```
   protected void buttonName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Pop", "openModal();", true);
    }
```

Comment: or if you have a separate JS file for showing the modal popup you could invoke it directly like this : `js/openModal.js` instead of `openModal();`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've tried your variant but unfortunatelly it is still not working, modal window does't appear.

Comment: Try this  : `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Pop", "<script type='text/javascript'> alert(1);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); alert(2);</script>",true);`

Comment: and tell me whether the alerts are fired or not

Comment: Got it! There was a mess with the names. Now it works correctly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help :) Mark the answer as ***accepted*** and vote-up so that others with the similar problems have a way to solve their problem :)